# Does a measurable function to the reals have to map every set to a Borel set?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

If we have a measure space $(X,S,\mu)$ and an $S$-measurable function $f:X\to \mathbb R$, then by the definition of measurability $f^{-1}(B)\in S$ for every Borel set $B$. Does this work the other way around? Is $f(E)$ a Borel set for every $E\in S$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $X=\mathbb R,$ let $\mathcal S$ be the Lebesgue measurable sets, and let $\mu$ be Lebesgue measure on $(\mathbb R,\mathcal S).$ The function $f(x)=x$ is Borel measurable (since every Borel set is Lebesgue measurable). However there are Lebesgue measurable sets $E$ that are not Borel measurable. For such an $E,$ $f(E)=E$ is not Borel measurable

Answer (score 2):

No.  Take a non-measurable subset $S$ of ${\mathbb R}$,  equipped with the
$\sigma $-algebra $\mathscr P(S)$,  and the counting measure.  Then the
inclusion of $S$ in ${\mathbb R}$ is a measurable map, but the image of $S$ under
this map is not a measurable subset of ${\mathbb R}$.